# Joining one table through other tables to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am struggling to articulate in a search query what I'm trying to do so I'm sorry if this has been answered before. I'm hoping that by posting a full example someone will be able to point me in the right direction. I'm looking to either figure out a mySQL query, or learn a better way to structure my database, to make the following possible.

If I have 4 tables, what is the best way to link through a table to another. Below I have a site_table that has an ID for a manager (General Manager of the site), a region and a country. The region_table and country_table also point at the manager_table. The manager_id on the site_table also points at the manager_table. Here are what the tables may look like:

```
site_table
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|    name    | manager_id | region_id | country_id |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| Manchester |          1 |         1 |          1 |
| Essex      |          2 |         2 |          1 |
| Perth      |          3 |         3 |          2 |
| Birmingham |          4 |         1 |          1 |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+

region_table
+-----------+---------+------------+
| region_id |  name   | manager_id |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|         1 | Central |          5 |
|         2 | South   |          6 |
|         3 | North   |          7 |
+-----------+---------+------------+

country_table
+------------+----------+------------+
| country_id |   name   | manager_id |
+------------+----------+------------+
|          1 | England  |          9 |
|          2 | Scotland |          8 |
+------------+----------+------------+

manager_table
+------------+-----------------+
| manager_id |      name       |
+------------+-----------------+
|          1 | Joe Bloggs      |
|          2 | Graham Smith    |
|          3 | Pat Sharp       |
|          4 | Sally May       |
|          5 | Peter Barratt   |
|          6 | Jimmy Stone     |
|          7 | Kim Keller      |
|          8 | Peter Sheet     |
|          9 | Matthew Lampart |
+------------+-----------------+
```

I would like to query the database to return the site name, General Manager's (GM) name, Regional Manager's (RM) name and Country Manager's (CM) name like so:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| site_name  |   GM_name    |    RM_name    |     CM_name     |
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Manchester | Joe Bloggs   | Peter Barratt | Matthew Lampart |
| Essex      | Graham Smith | Jimmy Stone   | Matthew Lampart |
| Perth      | Pat Sharp    | Kim Keller    | Peter Sheet     |
| Birmingham | Sally May    | Peter Barratt | Matthew Lampart |
+------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I feel like to do this I would have to link the site_table to the region_table and country_table, and then link the manager_table to the site_table, region_table and country_table but I'm tying myself up in knots trying to do it. I see the links looking like this:

```
site_table---+-----------------------+
             |                       |
             +-----region_table----manager_table
             |                       |
             +----country_table------+
```

If anyone can give any advice on the best way to write this query, or a better way to structure the database, that would be really helpful.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable schema design, *unless* the only information stored for a manager is their name (which seems unlikely).

Comment: Thanks @MarkBannister, you're correct there is more information in the manager table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` . Your idea is correct, you need to join first all three tables, and then as you can see I joined to manager tables on `m.manager_id IN(s.manager_id,r.manager_id,c.manager_id)` . The aggregation after is to pivot the output since there will be 3 records for each name, containing manager_name for each one of the tables.

```
SELECT s.name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.manager_id = m.manager_id THEN m.name END) as GM_NAME,
      MAX(CASE WHEN r.manager_id= m.manager_id THEN m.name END) as RM_NAME,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.manager_id = m.manager_id THEN m.name END) as CM_NAME
FROM site_table s
INNER JOIN region_table r ON(s.region_id = r.region_id)
INNER JOIN country_table c ON(s.country_id = c.country_id)
INNER JOIN manager_table m ON(m.manager_id IN(s.manager_id,r.manager_id,c.manager_id))
GROUP BY s.name
```

**If** you can have missing data - nulls on any of the site_table id columns, which doesn't sound very reasonable by the data you provided and even by the idea of this structure, then use a left join

```
SELECT s.name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN s.manager_id = m.manager_id THEN m.name END) as GM_NAME,
      MAX(CASE WHEN r.manager_id= m.manager_id THEN m.name END) as RM_NAME,
      MAX(CASE WHEN c.manager_id = m.manager_id THEN m.name END) as CM_NAME
FROM site_table s
LEFT JOIN region_table r ON(s.region_id = r.region_id)
LEFT JOIN country_table c ON(s.country_id = c.country_id)
LEFT JOIN manager_table m ON(m.manager_id IN(s.manager_id,r.manager_id,c.manager_id))
GROUP BY s.name
```

Comment: interesting...never seen that before

Comment: Thank you @sagi for your solution, it worked perfectly. I'm interested in the MAX(CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END) part, I'll definitely be reading up more on how that works. Thanks again.

Comment: @SBmore that `MAX(CASE..` is used to unite all records into a single one, the group by is not enough. Think about it, if I group by and use a normal max(m.name) , there are currently 3 manager names for each s.name, so the case is used to determine for each column which one should be used, and the max is because when the condition in the `CASE..` won't meat, it will put null value, and max will take the name. Hope I've made it more clear

Answer (score 3):

So the straightforward answer is:

```
select
  s.name site_name,
  gm.name GM_name,
  rm.name RM_name,
  cm.name CM_name
from
  site_table s
  inner join manager_table gm on gm.manager_id = s.manager_id
  inner join region_table r on r.region_id = s.region_id
  inner join manager_table rm on rm.manager_id = r.manager_id
  inner join country_table c on c.country_id = s.country_id
  inner join manager_table cm on cm.manager_id = c.manager_id;
```

But this really only works if there's always at least one region and manager for each GM, RM, and CM.  Something a little more flexible might be:

```
select
  s.name site_name,
  gm.name GM_name,
  rm.name RM_name,
  cm.name CM_name
from
  site_table s
  left outer join manager_table gm on gm.manager_id = s.manager_id
  left outer join region_table r on r.region_id = s.region_id
  left outer join manager_table rm on rm.manager_id = r.manager_id
  left outer join country_table c on c.country_id = s.country_id
  left outer join manager_table cm on cm.manager_id = c.manager_id;
```

Which will handle situations where you may be missing managers or regions, but is a little less efficient.

Hope these help!

Comment: 6 joins is  2 unnecessary joins!

Comment: Thanks for your help @CaffeineFueled. I've used sagi's solution to cut down on the amount of Joins needed. Thanks again for replying